# Returning host IP address into docker contain inside systemd configuration file

Tags: docker, systemd

Am working systemd configuration file, which needs a parameter of current docker host server. I tried following and it worked fine for me when i run directly

```
docker run -p 5555:5555 -e REMOTE_HOST="http://`/bin/hostname --ip-address`:5555" -e HUB_PORT_4444_TCP_ADDR=selhub.stage.internal -e HUB_PORT_4444_TCP_PORT=4444 --name=stage_selff stage_selff
```

But when I tried to add this into systemctl file,

```
[Unit]
Description=Selenium node container
Requires=docker.service
After=docker.service

[Service]
Restart=on-failure
RestartSec=10
ExecStartPre=-/usr/bin/docker kill stage_selff
ExecStartPre=-/usr/bin/docker rm stage_selff
ExecStart=/usr/bin/docker run -p 5555:5555 -e REMOTE_HOST="http://`/bin/hostname --ip-address`:5555" -e HUB_PORT_4444_TCP_ADDR=selhub.stage.internal -e HUB_PORT_4444_TCP_PORT=4444 --name=stage_selff stage_selff
ExecStop=-/usr/bin/docker stop stage_selff

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Its not working, I cannot find clear logs why, but am guessing the ` operator is not accepted by systemctl

Here is what the systemctl logs says

```
Sep 15 01:27:06 docker[831]: 21:27:06.337 INFO - Launching a Selenium Grid node
Sep 15 01:29:06 docker[831]: 21:29:06.668 WARN - error getting the parameters from the hub. The node may end up with wrong timeouts.Connect 
Sep 15 01:29:06 docker[831]: 21:29:06.675 INFO - Java: Oracle Corporation 25.45-b02
Sep 15 01:29:06 docker[831]: 21:29:06.678 INFO - OS: Linux 3.16.0-4-amd64 amd64
Sep 15 01:29:06 docker[831]: 21:29:06.690 INFO - v2.47.1, with Core v2.47.1. Built from revision 411b314
Sep 15 01:29:06 docker[831]: 21:29:06.735 INFO - Driver provider org.openqa.selenium.ie.InternetExplorerDriver registration is skipped:
```

Comment: Do you need the public ip? because the gateway IP within the container equals with the internal ip of the host.

Answer (score 0):

That construction wouldn't work, as `ExecStart` and it's siblings(like `ExecStartPre`, `ExecStop`, etc) don't use shell for operation, but rather `execve(3)` system call. That means that shell constructions like `$(command)`, `>`, `>>`, `<` and others have no effect.

See [Command lines](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.service.html#Command%20lines) for details.

You may try to employ `Environment` and `EnvironmetFile` options to pass values from outside of the unit file.